# Restricting API in WSO2 based on host header

Tags: wso2

We want to restrict API based on host header within WSO2. Is it possible to do it with configuration

WSO2

Answer (score 0):

You can write a global custom mediation sequence to get this done. See this for more details.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions